# implementing binary tree using python

Tags: python, binary-tree

i want to create a binary tree but the final result still wrong .

the binary tree expected output :

```
15 25 20 30 10 7 13 14 6 9 11 17 27 32 23
root node : 6
```

but my program current output is as below:

```
6 7 9 10 11 13 14 15 17 20 23 25 27 30 32
```

my big problem is the logical to insert the value to the node.

this my program:

```
class Tree:
    val = None
    left = None
    right = None
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def insert(self, val):
        if self.val is not None:
            if val < self.val:
                if self.left is not None:
                    self.left.insert(val)
                else:
                    self.left = Tree(val)
            elif val > self.val:
                if self.right is not None:
                    self.right.insert(val)
                else:
                    self.right = Tree(val)
            else:
                return
        else:
            self.val = val
            print("new node added")

    def showTree(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.showTree()
        print(self.val, end = ' ')
        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.showTree()
root= Tree(6)

root.insert(15)
root.insert(25)
root.insert(20)
root.insert(30)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(7)
root.insert(13)
root.insert(14)

root.insert(9)
root.insert(11)
root.insert(17)
root.insert(27)
root.insert(32)
root.insert(23)

root.showTree()
```

I'm still having trouble getting the correct result. i need your opinion to fix this.

Comment: Your "expected output" is actually the input order (except for the root). Is that really the output you must get??

Comment: On first glance: For the kind of tree you want (balanced; parents are always less than their children), you need to _replace_ the current value when the new value is lower, and propagate your current value to a child, recursively.

Comment: How to? where should i start? @L3viathan

Comment: yes yes the resulting output should be like that @trincot

Comment: So what is the logic of the output? What is the general rule? Some description of this challenge is missing...